# Writing program execution time to .txt file

Tags: fortran, fortran95

My IDE is Visual Studio 2010 with integrated Intel Fortran compiler. The version of compiler is: Intel Parallel Studio XE 2011

I have intention to write in `Output.txt` file some interesting things from program execution. In this case i want to write program execution time, or execution time for specific `do` loop or specific `do while` iteration loop because I want to know how much time every single loop takes.

Is there any way for doing that?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark In my first edition I did not saw that question is not there. My mistake!

Comment: Sorry, this is to broad. Start writing the code and once there is an actual problem you can't solve, show your code and describe the problem. There are many questions and answers about measuring execution time on this site. If you have a specific problem not covered by them you have to describe it in detail.

Comment: If the purpose is to make the code faster, you should look into _profiling_ your program. I don't know about your Intel compiler, but it probably has some profiling capability.